# Step-down transformer AC to DC voltage conversion problem?

Tags: voltage, transformer, diodes, rectifier, ac-dc

I got a step down transformer from an old black and white CRT TV that is about 18v 0 18v, 10A AC current output. I wanted to convert AC to DC, so used four 1N4007 diodes as a bridge rectifier. When I checked with a multimeter, it indicated +24v 0 -24v DC, so I wonder how that happened.

What happened to increase 18v 0 18v AC to +24v 0 -24v?

Did I do something wrong?

If so, what is the right way to do it?

Comment: It's probably not an exact duplicate but the answer on the following question explains why that happens: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48387/the-vdc-specification-of-a-transformer/48388

Comment: The peak voltage (Vpk) is bigger than the root-mean-square voltage (Vrms). Vpk = sqrt(2) x Vrms. The peak-to-peak voltage (Vp-p) is of course twice Vpk. This is for sinusoidal waves and ignoring reactive components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that the 18V reading is the RMS value when given an input of 110V, and you're inputting 117V and reading the peak value.
The conversion factor between RMS and peak for a sinusoidal waveform is sqrt(2); add the 110:117 increase in voltage and that's pretty close to what you're seeing.

You should also note that a bridge of diodes is not sufficient to get a clean DC signal -- there will still be a 120 Hz signal (with lots of overtones) after rectification, and you need to filter and regulate this to the voltage you need.
Add a couple of 470 uF or 1000 uF capacitors across the rectified signal (low ESR, and rated for 2x your expected input voltage!) and a linear regulator with sufficient current capacity, set to the actual output voltage you want, and you'll probably have a reasonable power supply.

An alternative is of course to build a switching power converter.

Comment: Before you said I have used couple of 1000uF capacitors that's the result I have mentioned before, So I want to decrease that transformer's output to +18v 0 -18v without using resistors. So how could I do that?

Comment: To do that, assuming you cannot change the input voltage, you either need to use a linear voltage regulator (which is kind-of like a self-regulating resistor) or a switching DC DC power converter. (Buck topology)

Comment: Can you provide suitable a linear voltage regulator circuit schematic or a DC DC power converter schematic?

Comment: The LM350 data sheet contains a schematic for a typical regulator -- two resistors in a divider to set the voltage, and two optional capacitors, and perhaps two optional diodes.

The MC34063 provides several good examples of how to build a switching DC DC regulator. Doing so is unfortunately a lot harder than dropping in a linear regulator, so if linear regulation is fine by you, that's what I'd suggest.